# ¿Cómo llamar a este método dentro de mi Main Java ¡CALL METHOD IN MAIN JAVA?

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

```
public class CalculateAverageArray {

    public static void main (String []args){

      //llamar el metodo calculateAverage aqui
      //call method calculateAverage here

    }


    public static double calculateAverage(double[] temperatures) {

        int size = temperatures.length;
        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

            total += temperatures[i];

        }
        double average = total /size;

        return average;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo `calculateAverage` es estatico y recibe un array de `double`. Como el metodo `Main` tambien es estatico y estan ambos en el mismo archivo, solo debes de ejecutarlo por utilizando el nombre del método:

```
public static void main (String []args){

 double[] dataEjemplo = new double[]{ 1, 2, 3}; 
 // llamamos el metodo
 double avr = calculateAverage(dataEjemplo );
 System.out.printl("El avr es:" + avr);
}
```

Comment: System.out.println("Average Temperature is: "+calculateAverage(new double[]{12.4, 10.2, 11.6, 15.5}));